# Combine SharePoint Lists in a different SharePoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, rest, csom, json

I have a task to create a SharePoint List that is a combination of 2 lists present on another SharePoint site.

There is no admin access to this site. Is is possible to get it and manipulate it?

Please provide the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to combine two list, the best way would it be to read the lists via REST or JSOM, write it into an array, sort it and than write it into html.

This is how you get the contents of a list:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/YOUR_SITE_NAME/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'YOUR_LIST_NAME\')/items';,        
    method: "GET",
    async: true,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
    success: function(resultsJSN){
        for(var i = 0; i < resultsJSN.d.results.length; i++) {
            $('#YOUR_DOM_ID').append('<ul>' + resultsJSN.d.results[i].Title + '</ul>')
        }
    },
})
```

Hope this helps (more code would be imo a little out of scope here )

Or do you just want to display two lists on a site? Than could just add two corresonding list webparts to a site:

1. Click on the gear-wheel icon and choose "edit page"
2. Click on "Add a web part"
3. Choose the list you want at "Apps"